# Assigning to relationship in core data object appears to corrupt the object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to create a child object and join it to its parent by assigning the parent id to the relationship in the child object. I use this code:

```
    Serial *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Serial" inManagedObjectContext:AppDelegatePtr.managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"context is %@", object.managedObjectContext);
    [object setValue:self.textNarrative.text forKey:@"narrative"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[SMNetworkModel sharedInstance ] selectedExerciseID]);
    [object setInExercise:(Exercise *)[[SMNetworkModel sharedInstance ] selectedExerciseID]];
    NSError *error;
    if (![AppDelegatePtr.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

However, it gives the following debug/error:

```
2014-11-02 23:36:49.622 RVP[4464:139260] context is <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7faf19fa1140>
2014-11-02 23:36:49.623 RVP[4464:139260] 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://D08DF3CD-A5E0-4445-B7C4-A84448110BDA/Exercise/p1>
2014-11-02 23:36:49.623 RVP[4464:139260] -[_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd000000000040000
```

The error is generated at line 5 in the above code. It seems that the parent object id (as in the debug) is somehow overwriting the managed object context property in the managed entity object. The relationship is one-to-one in this entity and one-to-many in the inverse. It doesn't affect the error if I change it to 1:1 inverse as well. If I comment out line 5, the object gets saved, but as an orphan.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you are doing is assigning ID values of relationships which is completely wrong.

Core Data is not a database. You don't manage tables that relate object to each other. You set objects as other objects relationships. I suggest you study Core Data Relationships a bit more.

Also, try using your own ManagedObject Subclasses; it does away with all the direct KVC accessing of properties and is a bit easier on the eyes. I would suggest using [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) once you get more comfortable with Core Data.

Comment: Thanks! 35 years of SQL has given me a certain rigidity of paradigm! In fact, I only had to change one line of code here and one elsewhere to store the object rather than the object id and it all burst into life. Thanks again.